# Can you cast Avada Kedavra on students and teachers?

Tags: hogwarts-legacy

I haven't unlocked the killing curse (Avada Kedevra) yet, but I have seen and used it in one of the battle arenas.

But now I am wondering: When you eventually unlock it later in the game as a normal spell, would I be able to use this spell on other students and teachers? Or is this spell exclusive to enemies in the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: **No**

---

Other answer: ***Yes** (with mods)

You can't use the Avada Kedevra spell on fellow classmates and teachers in the vanilla game, but you are able when using [mods](https://hogwartslegacy-mods.com/avada-kedavra-on-students/):

[image: Hogwarts Legacy - Killing Curse on Professor Sharp]